# Calculate Percentage Increase from Array - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

My db looks like this: (Sanitized Version)

```
[{
    "_id": 1,
    "Type": "Car",
    "Total": 82.03,
    "DateTime": "20210713T0834"
}, {
    "_id": 2,
    "Type": "Car",
    "Total": 20.26,
    "DateTime": "20210827T0834"
}, {
    "_id": 3,
    "Type": "Air",
    "Total": 50.43,
    "DateTime": "20210913T0834"
}, {
    "_id": 4,
    "Type": "Car",
    "Total": 42.03,
    "DateTime": "20210813T0834"
}]
```

I need to get the percentage increase each `Type` per `month`.

I tried to do it as follows:

1. Filter data in db for 2 consecutive months
2. Group the data by month
3. Group the data by type and outputs it to an array
4. Tries to compute the percentage increase from the array. This is the part I am stuck.

I feel that there is another proper way to do it and that I am doing too much work for it to work. Can anyone guide me?

Thank you.

The code for the above steps (Step 1 - 3) can be found here:

```
{"$match": {"DateTime": {"$gte": "20210701", "$lte": "20210901"}}},
{"$addFields": {"month": {"$substr": ["$DateTime", 4, 2]}}},
#Split by month
{"$group": {"_id":  {"month" : "$month", "type" : "$Type"}, "amount": {"$sum": "$Total"}}},
#Split further by types and create array
{"$group":{"_id": "$_id.type", "totalUSDPerTypePerMonth" : { "$push" : {"month":"$_id.month","type" : "$_id.type", "total" : "$amount"}}}},
```

I am getting this output so far:

[image: JSON Output]

How to proceed any further?

Thank you.

Comment: The first grouping can be on type+month.  And, after the second grouping you can use the values from the array, for each type, to calculate your percentage change. The change can be calculated with the first and second elements of the array (for each type). `$arrayElemAt` aggregate operator gets a specific array element.

Comment: I tried it and its becoming too nested, confusing and output errors. Is it the best way to go at it?

Answer (score 1):

- [`$setWindowFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setWindowFields/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$Type",
      sortBy: { DateTime: 1 },
      output: {
        sumOfThePreviousTotal: {
          $sum: "$Total",
          window: { documents: [ -1, 0 ] }
        },
        previousDateTime: {
          $push: "$DateTime",
          window: { documents: [ -1, 0 ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "previousDateTime": { "$toDate": { "$first": "$previousDateTime" } },
      "DateTime": { "$toDate": "$DateTime" },
      "perviousTotal": { "$subtract": [ "$sumOfThePreviousTotal", "$Total" ] }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "dateDiff": {
        "$dateDiff": {
          startDate: "$previousDateTime",
          endDate: "$DateTime",
          unit: "day"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "percentageIncreasePerDay": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$dateDiff", 0 ] },
          "then": 0,
          "else": { "$divide": [ { "$subtract": [ "$Total", "$perviousTotal" ] }, "$dateDiff" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/znGtM0b-pg_)

Comment: Pretty sure the calculation of `percentageIncreasePerDay` needs to be corrected.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes indeed, but its helping to know that we can do it this way